# Cassandra 2-node cluster with 5Tb drives each

Tags: cassandra

This is not for some fancy website like MyOwnFacebook but that's a data storage engine for data coming out of some scientific machine.

I'm wondering if there's any issue with large disks like that or if it would be better to split it, like 2 x (2 x 2 Tb) instead of 2 x (5 Tb).

I understand that a performance drop compared to something like 10 x (1 Tb), but will it be working at all? Will Cassandra complain?

Answer (score 1):

Official recommendations are:

- if spinning disk (7200RMP), do not exceed 1Tb/node (I would personally recommend only 500Gb/node)
- if SSD, you can go up to 3Tb -4Tb/node

Technically, nothing stops you from storing 10TB or more/node for example, but your node will die way before reaching that amount, the reasons are:

- full repair will take ages to finish (if you're not using incremental repair)
- unless you're using a properly tuned DateTieredCompactionStategy that stops compacting after some date threshold, compaction on a node with 10Tb will eat all of your disk I/O, even when using SSD
- rebuilding a 10Tb node after a failure can take a very loooooong time, especially if you lower the value for *streamingthroughput* to save some network bandwidth for your production

In a nutshell, the reason for those node density limits is to avoid having operational issues once in production

Comment: I understand the arguments. If one node has 2 disks of 1Tb, so 4 disk of 1 Tb in my cluster, will a disk failure on one node require the repair of the whole node ? I read somewhere that Cassandra knows about "JBOD" things.

Comment: For the JBOD thing, if you're not using **Cassandra 3.2**, you may face failure scenarios where deleted data are resurrected. See this blog post for more details on the issue: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improving-jbod